# 2011 Honda Civic Coupe Vibration in Reverse

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, civic

I have a 2011 Honda Civic and since it has been cold (winter in New England, US), from a cold start, idling or moving in reverse, the car vibrates but does not do it in park nor drive. At first I did not notice that the car did not do it some of the time - for example when it is warmed up after a drive and cannot fully cool by the time I finish in a store or something. Searching online yielded the following: loose engine mounts or snow in the front wheel wells, but neither seem to be the issue.

What might be the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not loose engine mount.

Bad/failed engine mount.

Easy to replace and a DIY project. If you do your own oil changes or brakes you can do an engine mount.

[image]

Picture courtesy of [YOUCANIC.com](http://youcanic.com)

Comment: I realized today there is a subtle vibration when in drive too. I'll take a look at it soon. Anything to say about how serious this is?

Comment: Honestly, people go a year or two with a bad mount but I wouldn't recommend it. Those vibrations are not good for any of the engine or car parts.